# Possible to place a chord diagram summary before the music notation in MusicXML or MuseScore?

Tags: chords, fretboard, musescore, musicxml

Is it possible to place a chord diagram summary (fretboard legend) before the score music in MusicXML or MuseScore? If yes, then how?

Background:

The chord diagram summary (i.e. fretboard legend) would include all the chords used in the piece in a single table. These chords would not be associated with any musical measures in the piece.

And, thus the music measures could just show the chord letters. This helps the overall music be more compact and facilitates a quicks review of the chords used.

Here is an example...

[image]

At this time, the information that I've found in MuseScore is [only for associating a Fretboard Diagram with a note in a measure](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/fretboard-diagrams).

Also, the [MusicXML Chord Symbols example](https://www.musicxml.com/tutorial/chord-symbols-diagrams/chord-symbols/) also only shows the Fretboard Diagram by assigned notes.

So, is either MuseScore or MusicXML capable of having a chord diagram summary before and not assigned to the music note/measure notation itself? If yes, how?

Comment: In MuseScore, you can select elements and drag them around the score. Have you tried attaching a fretboard diagram to a note and then moving it to the top of the score? You can also use horizontal lines to help with alignment (just make them white afterwards).

Comment: After you've printed the page into a PDF or other visual file for reading, does it cause some kind of a problem that the fretboard diagrams used to be technically associated with a note or rest in a measure in the MuseScore application? The idea is to produce written documentation for humans to interpret, isn't it. :)

Answer (score 4):

First create fretboard diagrams for the chords in the first bar, and then drag the diagrams where you want them to be on your page.

[image: drag guitar chord fretboard diagrams to MuseScore]

Then add labels for them, for example as chord symbols. Select a note or rest and press Cmd-K (maybe Ctrl-K on Windows), type the chord's name and drag it where you want.

[image: add labels for the fretboard diagrams]

This is MuseScore 2.x. It might be different in 3.x.